# Visual Studio 2017 search "all open documents" option seems to be missing

Tags: search, reporting-services, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) 'find in files':  In the search tool, the **"Look in"** option **"all open documents"** option seems to be missing from the dropdown.

I had found that option very handy in the past.

This option does work in my SSMS (17.7)

NOTE:  I subsequently found that this had to do with editing .rdl files for SSRS projects in design-view, see my own answer below, if interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2017, have you tried 'Find and Replace'?  *(ctrl + shift + f)*

I'm referring to this, inside 'Look In' drop down, you can select the scope.

[image]

Comment: For those using .rdl files for SSRS report projects in design-view, please see my very specific answer below; the above answer is generally correct so  I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is specific to .rdl files for SSRS report projects.  I found that if I have these files open in design-view (the default if you click on them) the option "find in all open documents" is not there.  However, if you open them as code [using F7], then the option returns.  This is somewhat surprising behavior, but apparently it doesn't consider the 'design-view' entities to be real documents, hence there are no open documents [in view of the IDE] and it does not consider this option valid under this condition.  Another mystery solved!  Since the answer above may be more generally helpful, I marked it as the correct answer.